# How can I make a google map marker and shadow bounce together?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google maps API v3 I add a marker and a shadow. I'm using this as a bit of a hack because I have 2 elements to my marker (type and status) so I use the shadow option to display my second image. When the user highlights a marker, I bounce it for one second. All that works fine except that the clever Google programmers have made made the marker bounce upwards and the shadow bounce at 45 degrees (approx 1.30 on the clock face).

The question: is it possible to make both images bounce upwards, so they are together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using custom icons where the shadow is "glued" into the same image is the easiest solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRkFp/ (click on the marker)

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html (see the Pins section)

I think I have seen the image files for the default marker somewhere if you must use those.

Comment: Thanks very much for the code (and for the link, which could be useful for many things). My problem is that I have 2 sprites with dozens of icons on each. I am trying to avoid making 1000+ images to cover all eventualities. I'll probably just end up not bouncing them :)